# Placing WidgetSet folder in vaadin WAR file

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a project that use add-ons which require widgetset . But  I am not sure where to place this widgetset folder in the war file which I deploy.

Please help.

Thank You 
Dhaval Maheshwari.

Answer (score 0):

`<web-root>/VAADIN/widgetsets`